# I have deployed my clientside webpart solution, but I can’t add it to my site

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-hosted-app, spfx-webparts, app

I created a sharepoint framework webpart and uploaded it to the app catalog. I enabled it for users to be able to add to sites. However, it’s not showing up in gallery when I choose to add an app.

Is there a step I’m missing somewhere?

Comment: check the Git hub link https://github.com/sharepoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/775

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, I have also deployed the web part to the App Catalog where is says it has been successful. I am unable to find the web part in the first link but it does show up as expected on the second link. I have verified that both description properties have a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get your part working on your local workbench and / or hosted workbench before uploading it to the app catalog?

If you type this into your browser (https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_api/web/GetClientSideWebParts) can you find your webpart listed?

If you go to your app catalog site, can you go to https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yourappcatalog/Lists/ComponentManifests/AllItems.aspx and see your webpart in the list of available components?

Also make sure to add Description and Short Description.
If there is no 'Description' and 'Short description',  Client Side WebPart don't show up in the modern page toolbox.

Comment: I did. I went through all these things you listed this morning. It seems to be working fine now.  Unfortunately, now that this one is working. All the others already deployed to the site seem to be broken now. Marking as accepted, because this helped me make sure everything was working as its supposed to